# Extracting case insensitive words from a list in django

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm extracting values from a csv file and storing these in a list.
The problem I have is that unless there is an exact match the elements/strings don't get extracted. How would I go about a case insensitive list search in Django/Python?

```py
def csv_upload_view(request):
    print('file is being uploaded')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        csv_file_name = request.FILES.get('file')
        csv_file = request.FILES.get('file')
        obj = CSV.objects.create(file_name=csv_file)
        result = []

        with open(obj.file_name.path, 'r') as f:
            f.readline()
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            #reader.__next__()
            for row in reader:
                data = str(row).strip().split(',')
                result.append(data)

                transaction_id = data[1]
                product = data[2]
                quantity = data[3]
                customer = data[4]
                date = parse_date(data[5])

                try:
                    product_obj = Product.objects.get(name__iexact=product)
                except Product.DoesNotExist:
                    product_obj = None
                
                print(product_obj)

    return HttpResponse()
```

Edit:

the original code that for some reason doesn't work for me contained the following iteration:

```py
for row in reader:
    data = "".join(row)
    data = data.split(';')
    data.pop()
```

which allows to work with extracted string elements per row. The way I adopted the code storing the elements in a list (results=[]) makes it impossible to access the elements via the product models with Django.
The above mentioned data extraction iteration was from a Macbook while I'm working with a Windows 11 (wsl2 Ubuntu2204), is this the reason that the Excel data needs to be treated differently?

Edit 2:
Ok, I just found this

> If your export file is destined for use on a Macintosh, you should choose the second CSV option. This option results in a CSV file where each record (each line in the file) is terminated with a carriage return, as expected by the Mac

So I guess I need to create a csv file in Mac format to make the first iteration work. Is there a way to make both csv (Windows/Mac) be treated the same? Similar to the mentioned str(row).strip().lower().split(',') suggestion?

Comment: `data = str(row).strip().lower().split(',')`

Comment: What's wrong with your code ? Is `product` a str or a list ?

Comment: product should be a str but to make it work I converted it to a list, initially believe it was a string with data = "".join(row) in the iteration but that somehow doesn't work on my wsl2 ubuntu, but sseems to be working on a Mac, not sure if that's even possible or I was missing something else

Comment: oh wait, I stored the list in results to get the elements into a list. when I then try to reference the elements from the csv as defined in Products models it doesn't work because it's only an element of the results list hmm :/

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is simply search for a string case **in**sensitive then all you gotta do is lower the case of your search and your query (or upper).

Here's a revised code

```
def csv_upload_view(request):
    print('file is being uploaded')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        csv_file_name = request.FILES.get('file')
        csv_file = request.FILES.get('file')
        obj = CSV.objects.create(file_name=csv_file)
        result = []

        with open(obj.file_name.path, 'r') as f:
            f.readline()
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            #reader.__next__()
            for row in reader:
                data = str(row).strip().lower().split(',')
                result.append(data)

                _, transaction_id, product, quantity, customer, date, *_ = data
                date = parse_date(date)

                try:
                    product_obj = Product.objects.get(name__iexact=product)
                except Product.DoesNotExist:
                    product_obj = None
                
                print(product_obj)

    return HttpResponse()
```

Then when you're trying to store the data make sure to store it lowercase.

Also, do not split a csv file on `,`. Instead use the Python's `CSV` library to open a csv file, since the data might contain `,`. Make sure to change `csv.QUOTE` so that it encapsulates everything with `"`.

Comment: not sure why but when inspecting the elements with print(type(product_obj)) I'm getting class 'NoneType' for all elements

Comment: @a56z make sure your data is also stored lowercawse

Comment: thanks, yes that's absolutely helpful thanks for that. I was rewriting the code a bit and it seems that the main problem here is that the way csv files are stored on Mac/Windows are different as Mac uses line feed on top of carriage return, so the "".join(row) results in a long single string, while on Mac it works perfectly storing everything in separate string values. I wonder if there's a way to unify csv's from Mac/Windows in code so that I don't have to write two versions?

Comment: use `from csv import reader`, which unifies the process.

Comment: oh really wow that's perfect I had no idea. Will have a look at how that works, again thank you, should be good now :)

Comment: wait __import csv__ is already there that's how I read the file with __reader = csv.reader(f)__ but I need to see how that documentation looks like, good point